# Please Fill Out This Field tooltip vs This Field is Required message in HTML Forms

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Are there certain conditions in which one of them appears and in other cases the other? 
I know that both appear when 'required' is used with a field in HTML form.

In validation Jquery, if I use `$("#register_form").validate({` directly, then I get the This Field is Required message in red color, for the empty fields, on submit.

But if for instance I have a check for recaptcha like this (and the validate part now goes into Else)-

```
jQuery('#register_form').on('submit', function(event) {
        var recaptcha = document.forms["donor_form"]["g-recaptcha-response"].value;
        console.log('recap val- '+recaptcha);
        if (grecaptcha.getResponse() == "") {
            console.log(grecaptcha.getResponse());
            jQuery("#captcha-reqd").html('reCAPTCHA is required');
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        else{
            $("#register_form").validate({
```

Then in this case I get the Please Fill Out This Field tooltip for empty fields.

Comment: validation plugin should be initialized on page load

Comment: Can you please elaborate.

Comment: You call `$("#register_form").validate({/*options*/})` outside the submit event listener. The submit event triggers the validation to occur